# Android set ImageButton background through url

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, imagebutton

I am trying to add background image to an ImageButton through a url.

I have modified the downloadimagetask from google android documentation like this.

```
class DownloadImageButtonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageButtonTask(ImageButton bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

I get an error :: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

on this line ::  Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());

I call this asynctask as

```
new DownloadImageButtonTask((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.my_image_btn))
            .execute("any image url");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set 
Try setting

```
if( e.getMessage()!=null)
{
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or simply

```
String exception= (e.getMessage()!=null)?ex.getMessage():"Exception occured";
 Log.e("Error", exception);
```

Comment: The logcat error is gone, the app doesn't force close, but the background does not appear on the imagebutton.

Comment: @user1910290 make sure that you are receiveing bitmap and is not null. Better use `UniversalImageDownloader` to download image.